# Angular 2 Response {_body: "[object Object]" after assign variable

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 app I'm sending a variable from service to component and in the template, I have a value, but when I trying to send this variable to a PHP script with POST I get [object Object] instead of a string.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FormService {

aForm: string[] = ['test1', 'test2'];

getData() {
    return this.aForm;
}


ngOnInit(): void {

  this.formServiceData = this.FormService.getData()
  this.name = (this.formServiceData[0]);
}
```

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(your object) to convert js object to string.

Answer (score 3):

You should stringify the JSON before you send it to your php service

```
JSON.stringify(yourObject);
```

In your PHP service you can decode the JSON using `json_decode()` function

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json)); // Will return objects
var_dump(json_decode($json, true)); // Will return assoc array

?>
```

Comment: Not working :(     
right now I'm sending array 2 times
    getDataToPOST() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.aForm);
  }     

AND   

 getData() {
        return this.aForm;
    }

Comment: In component temaplate is Ok  <li class="list-group-item">{{formServiceData[0].value}}</li> from getData

Comment: I have Error from getDataToPOST() --> ResumeFormComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Comment: Yes, this is not working, when I'm calling from the last component.

Comment: And this is Angular 2 not JS

Comment: Thanks for help imgURL: this.imgURL.value work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Before sending a variable with POST I need call **value** variable.value in php file:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $params = json_decode($json);
        $variable = $params->variable ;
```

Comment: my problems were connected with the difficulty of send Array of strings, sending JSON and single variables were the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was connected with sending a string array instead of JSON.